# Range.InsertFile method is broken in Word for Mac 2016

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I need to insert an HTML file from a macro in Word for Mac 2016 and the [InsertFile method from Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff835231.aspx) throws an error everytime I try to use it. I have tested the same code in Word 2011 and it works fine.

Does this happen to anyone else? Is there and alternative way to insert HTML code from VBA?

I've tried to do it calling an applescript from the macro and it takes ages.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file path passed to Range.InsertFile() in Word 2016 has to be in POSIX format instead of HFS like in Word 2011